# DevExpress.Web.ASPxListBox: How to format individual list items

Tags: asp.net, web, devexpress

How can I set the appearance of one or more **individual** items in a DevExpress.Web.ASPxListBox? I am **not** talking about setting the appearance of every item or the selected item(s).

For example, I would like to have some items highlighted in green and others highlighted in red, etc.

Thanks in advance,

Soenhay

EDIT:

I ended up using an ASPxGridView. And I accepted j0aqu1n's answer because he suggested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done for specific items on the server side. ASPxListBox does not have an ItemDataBound event which means that you cannot use binding expressions inside the  element. One way to do this is on the client using jQuery. You can mark the ASPxListBox items with a class:

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="ASPxListBox1" runat="server" >
            <ItemStyle CssClass="list-box-item" />
</dx:ASPxListBox>
```

and then use this class in the jQuery selector to customize individual items on the client. For example:

If you define this style in your CSS:

```
.even-row {
    background: Red;
}
```

Then on a client script block you do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').find('.list-box-item').each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).text() == 'True')
            $(this).parent().addClass('even-row');
    });
});
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: I am looking for a .list-box-item style inside a td just because I have columns defined inside the ASPxListBox. Depending on how you define your ASPxListBox it could generate different markup. You might need to inspect it with F12 in IE. Also, this is risky because future versions of DevExpress could decide to render ListBoxes differently. A more robust solution might be to use another control, like a GridView with one column to make it look the way you want. In this case you can customize the color of individual items.

Comment: That is true... I already started a GridView version yesterday ;)